# AS3 TweenMax: Is there any way to overwrite tween duration?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, overwrite, gsap

I'm working on a game, based on multiple entities with different "patience". If patence goes down, entity will die. Simple as hell.

Player have limited "boosters", if you give those boosters to entities, their patience is increased by 5;

```
public function initTimer (_count) {
    _count = _count + State.globalPatience;
    TweenMax.to(filler, _count, // counts back
            {width: 1 ,ease:Linear.easeNone,     //  and display it
                onComplete : Control.updateLifes,    // -1 life
                onCompleteParams : [this],           // and remove this entity
            });

}
```

This part works fine. 
But I'm stuck with the booster overwrite part.

```
public function updatePatience( _more):void // _more == 5
{   
    var current = TweenMax.getTweensOf(loader);
    trace('add: ' + _more + ' sec to : ' + loader.duration );

}
```

This traces: "add: 5 sec to : undefined"

The base idea was to grab the loader duration, and overwrite it. 
Or - kill the current Tween, and init another one with the updated duration. But it seems like I cannot even get the actual duration of the current Tween.

I hope someone can clear thing up for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you've got some weird code in `updatePatience`, you're settings `current` to `TweenMax.getTweensOf(loader)`, but you're never using it. Then, you're attempting to access the `duration` property on `loader`.

The easiest way to overwrite a tween in greensock is to use the `overwrite` property

From the documentation:

> overwrite : String (or integer) - Controls how (and if) other tweens
>   of the same target are overwritten. There are several modes to choose
>   from, but "auto" is the default

What I suggest you do is this:

```
TweenMax.to(filler, [your new count],
            {width: 1 ,ease:Linear.easeNone,
                onComplete : Control.updateLifes,
                onCompleteParams : [this],
                overwrite: "all"
            });
```

This will immediately update your tween.

That being said, you *can* access the duration of a tween:

```
public function updatePatience( _more):void // _more == 5
{   
    var current:Array = TweenMax.getTweensOf(loader);
    for each(var tween:TweenMax in current)
    {
        trace(tween.duration());
    }
}
```

Note: you can also update the `duration` by passing a value to that method. However, in my testing, that causes some erratic behavior (skipping).